# Beautifulsoup problem of scraping text in array

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Data=

```
<div class="dojoxGridView" id="dojox_grid__View_1" role="presentation" style="width: 1900px; height: 721px; left: 1px; top: 0px;" widgetid="dojox_grid__View_1">
       <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" dojoattachpoint="hiddenFocusNode" role="presentation" type="checkbox"/>
       <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" role="presentation" type="checkbox"/>
       <div class="dojoxGridScrollbox" dojoattachpoint="scrollboxNode" role="presentation" style="height: 721px;">
        <div class="dojoxGridContent" dojoattachpoint="contentNode" hidefocus="hidefocus" role="presentation" style="height: 504px; width: 1900px;">
         <div role="presentation" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
          <div aria-selected="false" class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" style="">
           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" style="width: 1900px;">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="0" role="gridcell" style="display:none;width:100px;" tabindex="-1">
               78126
              </td>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" role="gridcell" style="width:10%;" tabindex="-1">
               Approved Plan
              </td>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" role="gridcell" style="width:10%;" tabindex="-1">
               G-10
              </td>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="3" role="gridcell" style="width:40%;" tabindex="-1">
               ROOF PLAN
              </td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
          </div>
```

Input=

```
    source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
print(soup. prettify())
for article in soup.find_all('div', class_='dojoxGridContent'):
drawing_no = article.find_all('td', class_='dojoxGridCell', idx='3')
# ->need one more line to extract text
print(""drawing_no")
```

Output=

```
<td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="3" role="gridcell" style="width:40%;" tabindex="-1">ROOF PLAN</td> ...
```

I just want to extract "ROOF PLAN" how should I edit my code?
I tried drawing_no.text and drawing_no.value but it said "no attribute".
Thanks for your help!

Comment: just try with drawing_no.getText()

Comment: It gives error:   "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'getText'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: it is duue to find_all just add another for loop after or if only one element replace find_all by find

Comment: edited     drawing_no = article.find('td', class_='dojoxGridCell', idx='3') .
 it gives:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try followig code

```
source="""<div class="dojoxGridView" id="dojox_grid__View_1" role="presentation" style="width: 1900px; height: 721px; left: 1px; top: 0px;" widgetid="dojox_grid__View_1">
       <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" dojoattachpoint="hiddenFocusNode" role="presentation" type="checkbox"/>
       <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" role="presentation" type="checkbox"/>
       <div class="dojoxGridScrollbox" dojoattachpoint="scrollboxNode" role="presentation" style="height: 721px;">
        <div class="dojoxGridContent" dojoattachpoint="contentNode" hidefocus="hidefocus" role="presentation" style="height: 504px; width: 1900px;">
         <div role="presentation" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
          <div aria-selected="false" class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" style="">
           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" style="width: 1900px;">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="0" role="gridcell" style="display:none;width:100px;" tabindex="-1">
               78126
              </td>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" role="gridcell" style="width:10%;" tabindex="-1">
               Approved Plan
              </td>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" role="gridcell" style="width:10%;" tabindex="-1">
               G-10
              </td>
              <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="3" role="gridcell" style="width:40%;" tabindex="-1">
               ROOF PLAN
              </td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
          </div>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,"html.parser")
for article in soup.find_all('div', class_='dojoxGridContent'):
  drawing_no = article.find('td', class_='dojoxGridCell', idx='3')
  if drawing_no:
    print(drawing_no.get_text())
```

Comment: Error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: possible if certian if certain articles dont have table element with matching td check updated ans itonly prints if element exists

Comment: same error :(     "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: did you notice article.find change i replaced find_all

Comment: oh no, i did not, it works! gives: ROOF PLAN   but how do i get all element though?

Comment: all element means all td inside dojoxGridContent

Comment: i got it,   if drawing_no:
     for d in drawing_no:
         print(d.get_text())

Answer (score 0):

please try below code. But in general if you pass in idx=3 it will only return one single element. If you want to extract text from multiple element you might want to use a more general identifier.

```
import lxml
from lxml import html

html_string = """
<div class="dojoxGridView" id="dojox_grid__View_1" role="presentation" style="width: 1900px; height: 721px; left: 1px; top: 0px;" widgetid="dojox_grid__View_1">
  <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" dojoattachpoint="hiddenFocusNode" role="presentation" type="checkbox"/>
  <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" role="presentation" type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="dojoxGridScrollbox" dojoattachpoint="scrollboxNode" role="presentation" style="height: 721px;">
    <div class="dojoxGridContent" dojoattachpoint="contentNode" hidefocus="hidefocus" role="presentation" style="height: 504px; width: 1900px;">
      <div role="presentation" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <div aria-selected="false" class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" style="">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" style="width: 1900px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="0" role="gridcell" style="display:none;width:100px;" tabindex="-1">
                78126
                </td>
                <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" role="gridcell" style="width:10%;" tabindex="-1">
                Approved Plan
                </td>
                <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" role="gridcell" style="width:10%;" tabindex="-1">
                G-10
                </td>
                <td class="dojoxGridCell" idx="3" role="gridcell" style="width:40%;" tabindex="-1">
                ROOF PLAN
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(html_string)
ROOFPLAN = tree.xpath('//tbody/tr//td[@idx="3"]/text()')
print(''.join(ROOFPLAN).strip())
```

Comment: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: upvoted, by the way unlike bs4 it has no ",' between string, can i export it to csv or pandas?  it gives something like ROOF PLANLOWER GROUND FL. PLANGROUND FL. PLAN1ST FL. PLAN2ND FL. PLAN3RD FL. PLAN TO 14TH FL. PLAN & 16TH FL. PLAN TO 18TH FL. PLAN15TH FIRE RELIEF FL.19TH FL. PLAN20TH FL. PLAN TO 25TH FL. PLANCALCULATIONSHADOW AREA CALCULATIONSECTION A - ASECTION B - BNORTH-WEST ELEVATIONNORTH-EAST ELEVATIONSOUTH-EAST  ,without space

Comment: it would be more clear if you can share the source code as I dont know from above where the text is stored

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `idx` attribute and select by its value

```
print(soup.select_one("[idx='3']").text.strip())
```